# WCF Data Service, EDMX Entity Data Model, Oracle 11 database, not deploying to IIS

Tags: oracle11g, wcf-data-services

I am implementing a WCF Data service that implements the following method:
http://debugmode.net/2010/06/13/introduction-to-wcf-data-service-and-odata/

I've installed the following ***beta*** ODAC component:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/oracleefbeta-302521.html

When I run the solution in Visual Studio 2010, it returns data perfectly, when I deploy the application to IIS 7, it throws the following exception:

> *The underlying provider failed on Open.*

I checked the connection strings in both, they are set up identically, the only thing I can think of, which I believe is a non-issue is that the Oracle client components install the `TNSNAMES.ora` and `sqlnet.ora` in the following location:

There are 2 for the username

- `C:\app\<username>\product\11.2.0\client_1\Network\Admin`
- `C:\app\<username>\product\11.2.0\client_2\Network\Admin`

and there's one for oraclebase -

- `C:\app\oraclebase\product\11.2.0\client_1\Network\Admin`

I've copied the working files to all the right locations, in fact, I can connect perfectly fine via SQL Plus

My gut tells me that the application pool/identity that IIS is running under isn't loading the correct configuration values, but, I changed the app pool account to run under -my- account.

Here's the connection strings that are being used from the ASP.NET application (in case it helps)

```
metadata=res://*/ENTITY_NAME.csdl|res://*/ENTITY_NAME.ssdl|res://*/ENTITY_NAME.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string="DATA SOURCE=DATABASENAME;PASSWORD=PASSWORD;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=USERNAME"
```

By the way, I have another WCF data service on the same server, it's pointing to a SQL instance and pulling data just beautifully, there was an issue with the identity on that app pool, but that was resolved.

Anyone know what it might be?

Note: I am also doing a connection.open() and connection.close() on the entities in code.

Comment: Update: I hit the webservice directly and got the following error:

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue. The problem was that my application pool wasn't configured to enable 32-bit applications to run. The ODAC component is 32-bit.

In a round about kinda way, [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2010/01/26/connectivity-issue-with-oracle-in-x64-environment-ora-12154-tns-could-not-resolve-the-connect-identifier-specified.aspx) was helpful too, to help understand the various moving parts in configuring Oracle to connect.

Comment: yo do rock! it was exactly this.